# JsonIgnore attribute not work in abstract class

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I do not want some properties to be saved in the json file, so I used **[JsonIgnore]** Attribute but Does not work and all properties are saved

```
public abstract class SettingBase
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public abstract string FileName { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        JsonFile.Save(FileName, this);
    }
}

public static class JsonFile
{
    public static void Save<T>(string fileName, T @object)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(fileName))
        {
            options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
            options.Converters.Add(new PolymorphicJsonConverter<T>());
            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(@object, options);
            writer.Write(json);
        }
    }
}
```

I also use the following converter to solve the polymorphic problem

```
public class PolymorphicJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);
    }

    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value is null)
        {
            writer.WriteNullValue();
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var property in value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (!property.CanRead)
                continue;
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(value);
            writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue, options);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

and this is my demo

```
public class DemoSettings : SettingBase
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool boo { get; set; }
    public int integ { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }

    public override string FileName { get; set; } = "test.json";
}
```

I expect **FileName** and **boo** not to be saved in the file, but they are all saved

```
{
  "boo": true,
  "integ": 25,
  "str": "sss",
  "FileName": "test.json"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **Write** method extract all properties without any processing of **JsonIngoreAttribute**.

Because **GetType().GetProperties()** knows nothing about this attribute it returns all properties that you have.

If you want to ignore properties with this attribute, you need to modify your code something like this.

```
if (!property.CanRead || property.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>() != null)
    continue;
```